# Recurring profiles in magento - Maximum billing cycle

Tags: product, recurring

I am creating a subscription based product. But i am confused how to set it.

I need the subscription to be valid for 120 days (4months), so the user must be charged once every 120 days (4 months), in example, 10th January, then renew at 10th May, then at 10th September, etc. and go on until he/she cancels (it never ends until the user choose to cancel)

I think the “Maximum Billing Cicles” defines when it will stop (in example for monthly subscription, a 3 here: then it will be cancelled automatically after 3 months. I think, but not sure!). I want the subscriptions to renew infinite times, till the user cancels, so what may I write here? Nothing?

Billing Period Unit: Day? Month?

Billing Frequency: 120? 4?

Maximum Billing Cycle : (Nothing?)

Someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Billing Period Unit :** Month

**Billing Frequency :** 4

**Maximum Billing Cycles:**
If this is empty, the recurring profile will only end when the user or an administrator cancels the profile.

Source : http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-recurring-profile.html

Hope it helps you

Comment: what do i need to set for `Billing period unit` and `billing frequency` to charge once in 4 months ?

Comment: @Manashvibirla I have updated answer. `Billing Period Unit : Month` and

`Billing Frequency : 4`.